# $L_1$ norm of sum of orthogonal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that they are orthogonal i.e. $\langle x, y\rangle = 0$. We know that \[
\|x + y\|^2_2 = \|x\|_2^2 + \|y\|^2_2
\]
However, this is not true for other norms for example $\ell_1$ norm. For example, $x = [-1, 1]$ and $y = [1, 1]$. Is there a similar equality/lower bound inequality which holds for $\ell_1$. For example, for orthogonal vectors x, y, is the following true: \[
d \|x + y\|^2_1 \geq \|x\|_1^2 + \|y\|^2_1
\]

Comment: Well, we always have the *triangle inequality*: $\|x+y\|\le\|x\|+\|y\|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result you are claiming to be true, it IS TRUE! Because by the equivalence of the  norms there is a $c>0$ such that $\left\| x\right\|_{2}\leq \left\|x \right\|_{1}\leq c\left\|x \right\|_{2}$. It is easy to check that c can be taken as $\sqrt{2}$. Therefore $\left\|x+y \right\|_{1}^{2}\geq \left\|x+y \right\|_{2}^{2}=\left\|x \right\|_{2}^{2}+\left\|y \right\|_{2}^{2}\geq \frac{1}{2}(\left\|x \right\|_{1}^{2}+\left\|y \right\|_{1}^{2})$ which is what your claim was! In $\mathbb{R}^{d}$,  c can be taken $\sqrt{d}$ so the result is true in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and we proved the claim!!